# Yeoman Generator; What do these errors mean?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, firebase, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to install the angular-firebase Yeoman generator.  I get the errors listed below. What do they mean? I tried installing the generator with sudo and as a regular user. The errors were the same. I'd appreciate any help or guidance you could provide for this.  Thank you!

```
 npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0'
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0']
    npm ERR!   errno: 3,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'imagemin' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac/mcoseo7
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno 3
    npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/fs-extra/0.10.0'
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

app/index.html modified.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:86:
../src/constants.cc:10:66: warning: template argument uses unnamed type [-Wunnamed-type-template-args]
  object->Set(NanNew<v8::String>("kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone"), NanNew<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
                                                                 ^~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:290:1: note: unnamed type used
      in template argument was declared here
enum {
^
1 warning generated.
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished

    npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9'
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9']
    npm ERR!   errno: 3,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'phantomjs' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "karma-phantomjs-launcher" "karma-jasmine"   
"grunt-karma" "--save-dev"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/mac/mcoseo7
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno 3
    npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm/npmconf/2.0.9'
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

White-Macbook-2:mcoseo7 mac$ grunt
>> Local Npm module "grunt-autoprefixer" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-htmlmin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-imagemin" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-google-cdn" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-newer" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-ng-annotate" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-svgmin" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "newer:jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try sudo with the -g flag?

Comment: I tried that but when I run grunt it still tells me that it is not found.

Comment: did you run chown on the ~/.npm for the user you're using as well?  Then install whatever modules you are trying to add.

Comment: When I run chown -R 'whoami' ~/.npm it responds "Invalid argument". I did chown on both the global and specific user with and without sudo. No matter the combination I get "Invalid argument" in response.

Comment: can you try with a user/group name argument for the chown command?  also, can you share how you were using the sudo command with the previous command?

Comment: I'm a newbie so I don't know how to use an argument with chown. And for the second part of your question:

sudo chown -R 'whoami' ~/.npm

Answer (score 4):

either change permissions for npm using **chown** or use the **sudo -g** command to install modules.  This appears to be an issue with OS permissions.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to change permissions of npm with chown?

Answer (score 1):

`chown -R 'username' ~/.npm`

Yeoman scaffolds the app without errors after that.

Nik